# Popup box to view information according to the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'll be quick and short.

I have a ul with 4 Li, each li is a photo and I have 1 have one div with more information according to that image with a class name "java-popup" which will be my popup, this pop up when the user clicks. I am trying to code in jquery that when a user clicks on any of the image, the popup box will pop up with information according to that image.

Please, my aim is to produce a generic function that will take classname and add popup for that. I don't want to copy and paste the same code for each li.

so far:

## HTML

```html
<section id="java-projects">
  <!-- java-projects -->
  <div class="java-container">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <ul class="java-projects-gallery" id="gallery">
      <!-- ========= li ========= -->
      <li id="1">
        <div class="item-img">
          <img alt="Ink Transition Effect" src="img/HQCLogo.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="item-info light-bg" style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241)">
          <a href="http://www.hqcglobal.com"><em>HQCGlobal</em></a>  <i class="date">March 12, 2015</i>
        </div>
        <div class="feed" id="feed1">
          <div class="heart" id="like1" rel="like"></div>
          <div class="likeCount" id="LikeCount1"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- ========= li ========= -->
      <li id="2">
        <div class="item-img">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co">
            <img alt="Products Comparison Table" src="img/ChiChi.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-info light-bg" style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); position: relative;">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co"><em>ChiChi Logo</em></a>
          <i class="date">February 11, 2016</i>
        </div>
        <div class="feed" id="feed2">
          <div class="heart" id="like2" rel="like"></div>
          <div class="likeCount" id="LikeCount2"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- ========= li ========= -->
      <li id="3">
        <div class="item-img">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co">
            <img alt="Products Comparison Table" src="img/Gina.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-info light-bg" style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);position: relative;">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co"><em>Angelic Logo
            Praying</em></a>  <i class="date">April 4, 2016</i>
        </div>
        <div class="feed" id="feed3">
          <div class="heart" id="like3" rel="like"></div>
          <div class="likeCount" id="LikeCount3"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- ========= li ========= -->
      <li id="4">
        <div class="item-img">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co">
            <img alt="Products Comparison Table" src="img/Mashoom.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-info light-bg" style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);position: relative;">
          <a href="http://fullstackdeveloper.co"><em>M Logo</em></a>
          <i class="date">May 9, 2016</i>
        </div>
        <div class="feed" id="feed3">
          <div class="heart" id="like4" rel="like"></div>
          <div class="likeCount" id="LikeCount4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- ========= li ========= -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- \java-projects -->
```

## Js

```js
  $('#gallery li').on('click', function(event) {
    var id = this.id;
    if ($('.java-popup').hasClass(id)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      value = $(".java-popup").attr("class").split(' ')[1];
      a = "." + value;
      console.log($(a).addClass('is-visible'));
      //$(value).addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
      alert("Lost!");
    }
  });
```

Currently, the problem with my code is that, it is displaying one popup box with the same information with all the images.

I am trying to harcode my popbox so I can learn better, rather than using a popbox model which I know is available.

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I could, but it wont look good because there is much css into it, and js

Answer (score 0):

I made up this base of function, I think it will help you to finish what you want to do :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#gallery li').on('click', function(event) {
      var img = $(this).find('img');
      alert($(img).attr('alt') + " | li id => " + $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

And the JSfiddle for test : https://jsfiddle.net/1adjx6j8/1/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I figured it out another way. Here is the code:
  $('#gallery li').on('click', function(event) {
    var id = this.id;
    if ( $('.java-popup').hasClass(id) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var x = "#" + $('.java-popup.' + id).attr('id');
      $(x).addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
      alert("Lost!");
    }
  });